# Fabricjs getObjects return objects but with length 0

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

Here is my js code:

```
for (tagTemplateImage in tagTemplateImages) {
    var templates = tagTemplateImages[tagTemplateImage];
    for (templateId in templates) {
        $('.template-container').prepend('<div class="canvas col-lg-12" data-template-id="' + templateId + '"><canvas id="c-' + canvasIndex + '" data-index="' + canvasIndex + '" data-template-id="' + templateId + '" width="433" height="433" style="border:1px solid #ccc"></canvas></div>');
        canvas[canvasIndex] = new fabric.Canvas('c-' + canvasIndex, { preserveObjectStacking: true });
        canvas[canvasIndex].loadFromJSON(templates[templateId], canvas[canvasIndex].renderAll.bind(canvas[canvasIndex]));
        var canvastObjects = canvas[canvasIndex].getObjects();
        console.log(canvastObjects); //--> objects with properties
        console.log(canvastObjects.length); //--> 0
        for (o in canvastObjects) {
            console.log(o);//--> nothing shows here
        }
    }
}
```

On the for loop section it does not log anything.

[Here is the image for the logging of objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuNzt.png)

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
console.log(canvastObjects[o]);//--> something here now
```

Since `o` is a counter, you might like to make it `i`.

Update, I think the console should be showing something like this.  So I'm not sure you're actually getting back the objects.  Can you expand one?

[image]

Comment: Yes it is a counter, I'm expecting numbers to show there but nothing get logs.

Comment: @user7412793 Can you clarify the update I provided above?  Without seeing more of your code it is getting difficult to help further...

Comment: @user7412793 Did you need any further help with this?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I figure out the problem. I think loadFromJSON is a async function.